# file not found exception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am facing some problem while uploading image in laravel framework  of my project .I checked image is uploading to folder , but still this error is coming

[image]

Below is coding

```html
        /////////// Course Image ///////////
         $tmp_name1 = $course_image['tmp_name'];
         $type1 = $course_image['type'];
         $name1 = $course_image['name']; 


        $res1 = $this->upload_file($tmp_name1, $name1);
        if ($res1) {
            $course_image_url = $res1; 
        } else {
            $course_image_url = "";
        }



    function upload_file($source, $name) {

        $list = explode(".", $name);

        $ext = $list[count($list) - 1];
        $ext = strtolower($ext);
        if (in_array($ext, $this->file_extension)) {
            $filename = md5(date("YmdHis") . microtime() . rand(100, 100000000)) . "." . $ext;
            $destination = "public/uploads/" . $filename;
            $res = move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);

            if ($res) {
                return $destination = "uploads/" . $filename;
            } else {
                $message = "Internal server error";
                (json_encode(array("responseCode" => "500", "responseMsg" => array("status" => "error", "statusReason" => $message))));
            }
        } else {
            $message = "Invalid file extention";
            (json_encode(array("responseCode" => "500", "responseMsg" => array("status" => "error", "statusReason" => $message))));
        }
    }
```

There are lots of codes , I posted only the required one .

Comment: **I checked image is uploading to folder , but still this error is coming** ? means

Comment: this error is coming , but image is uploading to folder @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: Provide the controller code also ?

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Laravel Example for [Uploading Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files).

I.e., you can check if a file has been uploaded successfully using:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    //
}
```

And you can move / rename a file using:

```
$request->file('image')->move($destinationPath);
```

or

```
$request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that issue .

Go to line number 66 of this path(D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile.php) in your project folder .or search the text instanceof static.

After it remove the "instanceof static" ,then it is working fine.

Thanx